# InvalidOperationException: A key cannot be configured on 'ApplicationUser' because it is a derived type

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

when I create an account it works, no bugs, and logout works fine. But when I try to log back in a got this error:

> "Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context."

I ignored it because I wanted to work on some other things. When I added UserRoles with the seeding method it first worked fine, I guess, didn't get any errors. But when I did the thing with logging in I got the next error:

> "InvalidOperationException: A key cannot be configured on 'ApplicationUser' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'IdentityUser'. If you did not intend for 'IdentityUser' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not included in a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation property on a type that is included in the model."

I removed my old DB and removed the migration. When I try to add a migration (Add-Migration Users) I get the next error:
"A key cannot be configured on 'ApplicationUser' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'IdentityUser'. If you did not intend for 'IdentityUser' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not included in a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation property on a type that is included in the model."

I am trying to add custom Identity and UserRoles, I followed a tutorial on how to add custom data to your IdentityUser and a teacher gave us a tutorial on how to add UserRoles.

I am a beginner, using .net core 2.2 mvc with individual user accounts.

ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using application.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace application.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<IdentityUser> ApplicationUser {get; set;}
        public new DbSet<application.Models.Update> Update { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Seed.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using application.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace application.Data
{
    public class Seed
    {
        public static void SeedUsers(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            if (roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin").Result == null)
            {
                IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" };
                roleManager.CreateAsync(role).Wait();
            }

            if (userManager.FindByEmailAsync("admin@admin.com").Result == null)
            {
                ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    FirsName    = "Admin",
                    LastName    = "Admin", 
                    Email       = "admin@admin.com"
                };

                IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, "AdminTest420").Result;

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ApplicationUser.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace application.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirsName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

StartUp.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using application.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using application.Models;

namespace application
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddDefaultUI();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();


            app.UseAuthentication();
            //Seed.SeedUsers(userManager, roleManager);

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "Admin",
                  template: "{area:exists}/{controller=AdminHome}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the same issue by replacing all usage of IdentityUser to ApplicationUser. After inheritance `IdentityUser` by `ApplicationUser` you should work with ApplicationUser everywhere in code. Just make sure that you not referring to IdentityUser in you classes or view.

Actually you don't need this row

```
public virtual DbSet<IdentityUser> ApplicationUser {get; set;}
```

just read this article [custome user data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0#custom-user-data).

You can access to `AplicationUser` via DI

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public MyController(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by `public virtual DbSet<IdentityUser> ApplicationUser {get; set;}`.

For `ApplicationUser`, you could access the `AspNetUsers` table by `_context.Users`.

For customing the identity, follow this [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2)